# iOS 7 style transparencies/animations in Sencha or HTML/CSS

Tags: css, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, ios7

I am creating a mobile app with an iOS 7 theme, meaning lots of transparencies, blurs, and animations.

Does anyone know if the current JS frameworks out there (blur.js, [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/image-filters/)) will suffice in terms of performance for blurs and transparencies?  Or am I stuck with going the native route.

Comment: Heh, got the "Popular Badge" for this question but with only one downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the best question in the world, but in short, yes. I've been working on a similar project and have almost completed it. I can assure you the vast array of available CSS and jQuery markup will be sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7 Bootstrap:

https://github.com/brandonjordan1/iOS7-bootstrap

It's only in it's first version but it's the only one.